# Windows 11 transparent popup appearing over apps

Tags: windows, windows-11

I recently installed windows 11 and there's this transparent card (Similar to a card with box-shadow property in HTML) that keeps on poping up over applications. Any content behind it is not clickable. I have tried checking the task manager but am unable to locate the process running it. Is there any possible fix?

[image: Screenshot]